# Autowired bean injection in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring

Not able to figure out, what's wrong. I keep getting the same error again and again. I have searched Google but failed to solve this issue. I was looking the same post over here try to solve but still the same.

**JobsDAOImp.java**

```
public class JobsDAOImp implements JobsDAO {

    @Autowired 
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        ..        
}
```

**JobService.java**

```
public interface JobsService {
       ....
}
```

**JobServiceImp.java**

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class JobsServiceImp implements JobsService {

    @Autowired private JobsDAOImp jobsDAOImp;
        ..
}
```

**JobsController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public class JobsController {

    @Autowired
    private JobsService jobsService;
            ...
}
```

spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config/>        

        <!-- DAO Implementations -->
        <bean id="usersImp" class="org.delance.daoimplementation.UsersImp" />
        <bean id="jobsDAOImp" class="org.delance.daoimplementation.JobsDAOImp" />

        <!-- Service Implementations -->
        <bean id="jobsServiceImp" class="org.delance.serviceimp.JobsServiceImp" />  

        <bean id="dataSource" class="${jdbc.dataSource}" destroy-method="close">
               <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"/>
               <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.jdbcUrl}"/>
               <property name="user" value="${jdbc.user}"/>
               <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
               <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}"/>

               <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${jdbc.acquireIncrement}" />                   

               <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${jdbc.idleConnectionTestPeriod}" />  
               <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${jdbc.checkoutTimeout}" /> 
               <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="${jdbc.unreturnedConnectionTimeout}" /> 
               <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
               <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
               <property name="automaticTestTable" value="${jdbc.automaticTestTable}" /> 
               <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="${jdbc.testConnectionOnCheckin}" />                 
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
               <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

               <property name="packagesToScan">
                            <array>
                               <value>org.delance.models</value>
                            </array>
               </property>               

               <property name="hibernateProperties">
                 <value>
                   hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                   hibernate.cache.provider_class = org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
                   hibernate.show_sql = true
                   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
                 </value>
               </property>               

        </bean>                

        <context:property-placeholder location="application.properties" />
</beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.delance" />

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
           class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/" />            

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

getting this issue :-

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delenace.service.JobsService org.delenace.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delenace.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delenace.service.JobsService org.delenace.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delenace.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delenace.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 28 more

Feb 18, 2014 5:01:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delenace.service.JobsService org.delenace.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delenace.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:656)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1635)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.delenace.service.JobsService org.delenace.controllers.JobsController.jobsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delenace.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.delenace.service.JobsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Why do you both put `@Service` annotation **and** define bean in xml configuration? And by the way (unrelated) why not declaring `jobsServiceImp` field as `JobsService` (interface)

Answer (score 6):

Use the interface instead of the implementation in the `JobsController` since spring generates a java proxy for the `JobServiceImpl` bean and java Proxies are based on interfaces.

```
 @Autowired
 private JobsService jobsService;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your whole project and what's the exact configuration, but it seems to me that you are loading only mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml without spring.xml. In your case this is OK because you have defined

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.delance" />
```

to scan for bean definitions. So assuming you have only the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml loaded, you should check that both of the controller and service are in a package that has this common base package "org.delance" or otherwise spring classpath scanning won't pick them up. Also you should get rid of the qualifier - this is in case you have two or more beans of given type.
Anyway I have had this kind of problems before and I am sure it will be something small.

Regarding tha fact you have 2 configurations (or also contexts) there's something more you have to consider. You shouldn't define one bean twice (once through package scanning and second time in the xml config), except when this is done intentionally. Having this said if you fix this first issue you'll have other problems when you load both of the contexts (spring.xml and mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xm)

Answer (score 0):

You need make the jobService.java class to be bean specified. Add stereo type annotation to it like @Component.

Answer (score 0):

if you use such definition:

`<bean id="jobsServiceImp" class="org.delance.serviceimp.JobsServiceImp" />`

you are not leveraging Spring Dependency Injection feature, since there is no difference between interface and implementing class; in Spring, you might want to use interfaces throughout the code and declare their implementations in the application context configuration (this is defined as separation of concerns); this is also useful in case you decide to change the implementation because you will just need to change the xml configuration.

Please try the following:

`<bean id="jobsService" class="org.delance.serviceimp.JobsServiceImp" />`

Salvatore